# Width of fence gate for heavy construction vehicles to drive through

Tags: wood, doors, fence, construction

We live in corner lot with 20-24 ft drop in elevation and plan on doing a home addition requiring heavy equipment. There’s a cedar fence around perimeter of entire lot. Currently only way for vehicles to drive in to backyard is to go up a 4 ft tall rock staircase -3 steps- through a standard 4 ft wide gate beside driveway.

Since that’s probably not feasible would turning a section of fence in to gate behind stop sign work?
How wide will gate need to be?

House and driveway in blue below. Trees in green.

[image: rough drawing]

Comment: Somewhere in the 20 - 30' range, depending if the vehicles need to turn onto the road. The best I can suggest is see what the contractor needs he/she is the best judge.

Comment: Do you need the fence?  Will your llamas get lloose and roam the neighborhood?

Comment: @Willk ;-) they will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most all heavy equipment is under 10’ -12’ wide max and that requires wide load so it depends how big a tracked shovel or Track hoe you might need. To tell the truth most homes won’t need more than a extend-a- hoe back hoe and these can fit through a 8’ opening mini Cranes again are only 8-9’ wide so in reality the heavy equipment needed for a home will be fine at 10’.

Comment: or 9'9" (which is what you get when you remove the fence between two ordinary 10' spaced posts.